# When is a Bounty appropriate/OK?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I'd like to start a bounty on one of my questions because it hasn't received and adequate answer yet, and it's an unanswered question I've had for a long time.  Is this a good reason to start a bounty or a bad one?

What are the acceptable reasons to bounty your own question, and what aren't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're referring to is precisely the reason the bounty system was originally created. It wasn't until much later that the option was added to add bounties on *other* people's questions.

So yes, go ahead and start the bounty. You'll also get to specify a reason, or pick from one of a few predefined reasons (one of them being "this question hasn't received enough attention").

Comment: Was there any kind of post about how to use the different bounties? I was digging through old answers of mine and found an abandoned question with no marked answer and wanted to bounty it to get an answer auto-awarded; that doesn't seem to be a suitable purpose to any of the bounty descriptions. Would 'draw attention' fit, [even if it's not a particularly interesting question?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16435/how-can-i-fix-a-mole-sauce-with-excessive-cinnamon)

Comment: @mfg: Well, what *is* your reason for wanting to bounty it? Is your objective simply to draw more attention to the question? If so, then yes, it fits, that's the point of a bounty; if it was already interesting then you wouldn't need a bounty to draw attention to it.